# Create "_Enter" event handler for textbox in class module

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Class Module, `TCLabel`, to add event handlers for a dynamically populated userform. When the userform is initialized, these labels (and other controls) are dynamically added based on the custom document properties of `ActiveDocument`. Everything is working correctly, except I have found that I am unable to create `Textbox_Enter` event handlers using the class module. Here is the code from the module:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents m_oTextBox As TextBox

Public Property Set TextBox(ByVal oTextBox As TextBox)
    Set m_oTextBox = oTextBox
End Property

Private Sub m_oTextBox_Change()
    MsgBox "Success: Change"    '<--Works
End Sub

Private Sub m_oTextBox_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    MsgBox "Success: DblClick"    '<--Works
End Sub

Private Sub m_oTextBox_Enter()
    MsgBox "Success: Enter"    '<--Doesn't work
End Sub
```

In the drop-down menus for the class module, there are options only for `BeforeDragOver`, `BeforeDropOrPaste`, `Change`, `DblClick`, `DropButtonClick`, `Error`, `KeyDown`, `KeyPress`, `KeyUp`, `MouseDown`, `MouseMove`, and `MouseUp`, but no option for `Enter`. Manually creating the event, as seen in the code above, does nothing. `Enter` is a valid event handler for a textbox, why can it not be created with a class module? Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: The MSForms `TextBox` actually *doesn't* have an `Enter` event.  You can verify that the events you listed are the only ones available in your Object Browser.

Comment: Those are the only ones available in the Object Browser for the class module, but when I create a textbox on a userform, `Enter` does show up in the Object Browser, and code added there runs as expected.

Comment: [Screenshot of `Textbox_Enter` event](http://imgur.com/Qxp9y2a). That's what you're talking about, correct? Or am I missing something?

Comment: OK that's truly bizarre, never noted that before.  I wonder if it has something to do with how the typelib is defined - unfortunately fm20.dll is crashing my typelib browser...

Comment: So all I'm looking to do is fire an event when a user clicks one of these textboxes, and after reading into the descriptions of the events it looks `MouseDown` may be able to do what I want. It's not quite what I'd like (it's interfering with `DblClick` events), but I think I might be able to make it work.

Comment: OK, so I busted open the typelib and verified that it really doesn't have an `Enter` event, hidden or otherwise.  The events are extended on the `MdcTextEvents` dispinterface, and there aren't any `Enter` or `Exit` events.  I wonder if VBA is doing some sort of forwarding based on the message pump (i.e. simulating an "event" when it gets a `WM_SETFOCUS` message or something like that).

Comment: Alright, well that at least answers why I can't do it. Still a bit frustrating, but I'll manage. If you want to submit that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: There's still a way to do it - it just depends on how much work you'd want to do.  You can do the same thing VBA apparently does and subclass the `TextBox`.  Then *you* can listen for `WM_GETFOCUS` messages.

Comment: My understanding is that `_Enter` and `_Exit` events are Userform related. Hence, they are not _purely_ textbox events, and do not show up in custom classes as such.